# Uncaught TypeError svg.selectAll is not a function in D3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg

```
 //var svg = <svg>my svg stuff</svg>

                var a= svg.selectAll("image").data([0]);
                    a.enter()
                    .append("svg:image")
                    .attr("xlink:href", "file:///D:/logo.png")
                    .attr("x", "60")
                    .attr("y", "60")
                    .attr("width", "50")
                    .attr("height", "30");
```

I am trying to append an image to my svg using d3.js, but I am getting the **"Uncaught TypeError svg.selectAll is not a function in D3.js"** error. What am I doing wrong? I found the similar question but it didn't helped me to solve this.

Comment: What do you mean var svg = markup? What exactly are you doing there?

Comment: May you show an example of the SVG code?

Comment: By var svg I mean svg has this data 

"<svg> <text x="130" y="130" style="font-family:Segoe UI;font-size:20px;font-weight:400">This is my sample text</text> </svg>"

And it will be used to export svg into pdf.

Comment: You're doing this totally wrong. If you want to join the data, `svg` has to be a **D3 selection**. Like `var svg = d3.select("svg")`.

Comment: var svg = d3.select("svg")
                        selectAll("image").data([0]);
                        svg.enter()
                        .append("svg:image")
                        .attr("xlink:href", "file:///D:/logo.png")
                        .attr("x", "60")
                        .attr("y", "60")
                        .attr("width", "50")
                        .attr("height", "30");

Is this fine?